# Winedt PDFLaTeXify not working

Tags: pdftex, winedt

I moved to a new machine and can't get texify to work. Everything else works - I can use PDFLaTeX to run the .tex document, run biber, then PDFLaTeX repeatedly to get the desired PDF. But PDFLaTeXify gives me the error "object 'errorstopmode' not found."

Options: Execution modes: Diagnosis says my Miktex installation appears to be fine.

Any suggestions?

I'm running Winedt v 10.3, build 20180507. LaTeXify is installed and up to date.

Thanks!
Gordon

Here are the settings for PDFTeXify. Are any others needed?

[image]

This setup allows me to use knitr directly in WinEdt, to edit/compile .Rnw documents (combination R code and output + LaTeX). One source for this instruction is https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/editors/.

But perhaps that's outmoded. I see that the RManager plugin has no such instructions. Maybe I should experiment resetting this to the default settings. Do you know what they are?

Well, that was a silly request. I see how to reset to default - and it's now more or less working. Doesn't seem to actually run Biber but I'll fool around a bit - at least I'm on the road to getting it fixed!

Comment: can you run it on a command line?

Comment: No. Is there supposed to be a latexify or pdflatexify executable somewhere? Or am I missing the point of your question (I'm assuming you mean something like [pdf]latexify myfile.tex)?

Comment: Both latex myfile.tex and texify --pdf myfile.tex do run fine from the command line.

Comment: Then you will have to show the relevant winedt settings.

Comment: Well you seem not to use texify but RScript.exe, but I can't tell you how you got there and if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that runs into this problem (PDFLaTeXify not running due to setup w/ RManager), it's actually a simple fix: forget the ancient settings. Things will now run close to out of the box. Settings that are now working for me are below.[image]

And these for Biber to run automatically as part of the process. [image]

Many thanks to Ulrike Fischer for setting me on the road towards the solution.